# Can buttons be added to a ToolbarWindow32 control at design time?

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, dialog

Can I use the Resource Editor of dialogs from VS2022 to add buttons to a Toolbar?

The Toolbar is defined in the .rc file as:

```
CONTROL         "Custom1",IDC_CUSTOM1,"ToolbarWindow32",WS_TABSTOP,7,7,315,21
```

I have found only examples of how to add buttons at runtime, not design time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I use the Resource Editor of dialogs from VS2022 to add buttons to a Toolbar?

Sort of, but not really.

The system doesn't provide a way to declare [toolbar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/toolbar-control-reference) buttons in a resource script that are automatically added to the toolbar as part of dialog creation. Buttons always have to be manually added at run-time.

If you're writing a standard Win32 Desktop application the story ends here.

---

On to the *"sort of"* part then. Given the above is true, it may come as a surprise that Visual Studio does provide a [toolbar editor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/toolbar-editor). Out of all the standard resource editors, this is the odd one out. The hint is subtle, at the very bottom of the documentation that reads:

> **Requirements**
>
> MFC or ATL

The editor operates on a custom, private resource type ([`RT_TOOLBAR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/tn024-mfc-defined-messages-and-resources#rt_toolbar-resource-format)), introduced and used by the [Microsoft Foundation Classes (MFC)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/mfc-concepts). The basic idea is to have the graphical resource editor dump an `RT_TOOLBAR` (binary) resource that's picked up at run-time by the framework (MFC), parsed back into structured data, and used to construct the buttons.

The buttons *still* have to be manually added at run-time. The only difference is that someone else has written the code to do this, so we don't have to.

---

In theory, one *could* reuse part of this machinery in a standard Win32 Desktop application that doesn't use MFC. The binary data behind an `RT_TOOLBAR` resource isn't very complex and the MFC source code (e.g., *bartool.cpp*) is sufficient to deduce its meaning.

Still, there are several implications and limitations, and no official (contractual) documentation to rely on, so it's best not to.